# Is it possible to tell if a file's message digest is MD5 or SHA-256?

Tags: openssl, md5, sha256

There's some old data encrypted with OpenSSL 1.0.2, but now OpenSSL is at 1.1.0.  I understand from [OpenSSL FAQ USER3](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3) that an old file can be decrypted with 1.1.0 by using `-md md5`.  But let's say you had newly encrypted files too?  Then some would have a SHA-256 message digest, and some would have an MD5 message digest.  Is there a way, looking at the file before using 1.1.0 to decrypt it, that you can tell which was used to encrypt it, 1.0.2 w/MD5 message digest, or 1.1.0 w/SHA-256 message digest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot tell just by looking at the encrypted file. The encrypted file itself is nothing more than the *raw* ciphertext output of OpenSSL. It does not retain any metadata (such as a hash of the key, the algorithm, or the IV) other than the salt, which is included by default. The hash algorithm used to convert the input password into the key (and IV) is not recorded anywhere in the resulting message.

Be aware that OpenSSL is *not* supposed to be used for secure encryption. It is a utility for testing the OpenSSL library only. It has many security weaknesses when used for encrypting sensitive data on the command line. The lack of key stretching, integrity, metadata, and unique IV come to mind.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that’s what I thought, but I wasn’t sure.

Comment: The `enc` format _does_ record the salt input to the PBKDF, but not the PBKDF hash and not the (subsequent) cipher algorithm-and-mode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OpenSSL's `enc` does not use PBKDF2.

Comment: I didn't say PBKDF2. I didn't even say PBKDF1, which EVP_BytesToKey _almost_ uses.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I was under the impression that KDF was the term for any key derivation function, whereas PBKDF is a specific class of KDF (i.e. only PBKDF1 or PBKDF2). Or at least, I've never seen the term _PBKDF_ on its own. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: PBKDF is any Password-Based Key Derivation Function, just as KBKDF is any Key-Based one, and both are subclasses of KDF, much as block symmetric ciphers and stream symmetric ciphers are importantly-different subclasses of symmetric ciphers. PBKDF1 and PBKDF2 in PKCS5v2+ (PKCS5v1 didn't use these names) are specific standardized PBKDFs (actually they're really specific only after adding parameters, which are simple for 1 and more complex for 2) but others are used and infinitely many are possible.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I didn't know that. Well, the more you know!